# Solutions to differential equations that make use of the entire function up to a point?

Tags: real-analysis

When defining a function on natural numbers, we may define it recursively so that it makes use not just of the function's argument, but the previous value of the function, i.e.

$$ y (0) = y_0 $$

$$ y (n+1) = g (n, y (n)) $$

has a unique solution $y$ for any $y_0, g$.

Moving from discrete to continuous, the obvious analog to a recursive definition is a differential equation, so the general situation looks something like

$$ y(0) = y_0 $$
$$ y'(x) = g(x, y(x)) $$

where existence and uniqueness is covered by something like Picard–Lindelöf.

Returning to the discrete, a recursive definition can make use of not just the previous value, but *all* previous values, i.e.

$$ y(n) = g(n, \lbrace y(k)\rbrace_{k<n}) $$

has a unique solution for any such $g$.

We can imagine an analogous situation in the continuous:

$$ y'(x) = g(x, y\vert_{[0,x)}) $$

where $g$ is now some sort of functional taking an $x \in [0,\infty)$ and a function $f : [0,x) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Are there any theorems that cover the existence of solutions to such differential equations?